# Knockout.js providing incorrect $root

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following knockout.js view models defined:

```
    function EoiLineItemViewModel(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.LineID = ko.observable(data.LineID);
        self.QuoteID = ko.observable(data.QuoteID);
        self.Quantity = ko.observable(data.Quantity);
        self.UnitPriceExTax = ko.observable(data.UnitPriceExTax);
        self.UnitPriceTaxRate = ko.observable(data.UnitPriceTaxRate);
        self.UnitPriceTaxAmt = ko.observable(data.UnitPriceTaxAmt);
        self.UnitPriceTaxInc = ko.observable(data.UnitPriceTaxInc);
        self.LineTotalExTax = ko.computed(function() {
            return self.Quantity() * self.UnitPriceExTax();
        });
        self.LineTotalTaxAmt = ko.computed(function() {
            return (self.LineTotalExTax() * (1 + (self.UnitPriceTaxRate() / 100))) - self.LineTotalExTax();
        });
        self.LineTotalIncTax = ko.computed(function() {
            return self.LineTotalExTax() + self.LineTotalTaxAmt();
        });
        self.ClientState = ko.observable(data.ClientState);
    }

    function EoiViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.QuoteID = ko.observable();
        self.LineItems = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.CurrencyID = ko.observable();
        self.SupplierRef = ko.observable();

        self.DeliveryDate = ko.observable();
        self.QuoteAvailablityStartDate = ko.observable();
        self.QuoteAvailablityEndDate = ko.observable();

        self.OpeningComments = ko.observable();
        self.PricingComments = ko.observable();
        self.DeliveryComments = ko.observable();
        self.TermsComments = ko.observable();
}

    var items = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.LineItemsAsJson)');
    var mappedItems = $.map(items, function(item) { return new EoiLineItemViewModel(item); });
    var vm = new EoiViewModel();
    vm.LineItems(mappedItems);
    console.log(vm);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
```

And the following html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveQuoteDraft", "Supplier"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <textarea name="EoiDraftModel" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON($root)" class="may-frm-textarea"></textarea>
    <div style="margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 100px; text-align: right;">
        <p>
            @Html.LocalisedActionLink("Cancel", "Browse", "Many")
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-success" />
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

What id dont understand is why the textarea only contains:

```
{"LineItems":[{"LineID":1,"QuoteID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","Quantity":0,"UnitPriceExTax":0,"UnitPriceTaxRate":0,"UnitPriceTaxAmt":0,"LineTotalExTax":0,"LineTotalTaxAmt":0,"LineTotalIncTax":0}],"FreightExTax":0,"FreightExTax2":0,"FreightTaxRate":0,"FreightTaxAmt":0,"FreightIncTax":0,"TotalLinesExTax":0,"TotalLinesTaxAmt":0,"TotalExTax":0,"TotalTaxAmt":0,"TotalIncTax":0}
```

Why is

```
$root = self.LineItems
```

I would expect the entire EoiViewModel() to be listed/serialized not just the single property of LineItems? The same is true for $data. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

O.k so its because I'm an ass. $root IS binding to the vm as I would expect but because the properties have no values they dont show up in the ko.toJSON($root).

ko.toJSON($root) only display properties with actual values. I guess to make any payload smaller...but i didn;t know that.

If I do this:

```
   self.OpeningComments = ko.observable("");
            self.PricingComments = ko.observable("");
            self.DeliveryComments = ko.observable("");
            self.TermsComments = ko.observable("");
```

They show up. Duh!